# BizTalk Warning messgage

Tags: biztalk

I am trying to remove the warning in my BizTalk project.
Getting lot of warning similare type saying

> Warning CS2002: Source file 
>   Warning 58  Source file 'C:\c\project1\Schemaex.xsd.cs' specified multiple times    C:\c\project1\csc

How to remove this warning?

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, Warnings are just that, Warnings.  Unfortunately, Warnings have been a side effect of the BizTalk SDK since the beginning and for the most part can be safely ignored.

My advice, don't worry about it.